Are sentences like 'How odd that is!' SOV and can sentences like that be made with verbs besides 'to be'? What is 'how' exactly in these sentences?
Today while texting my friend, I decided to jocularly send 'How very queer you are!' To me, this sentence sounds correct, but I can't quite understand how it works. Is English not an SVO language? Why would the complement precede the subject and the verb? This looks like an OSV/SOV sentence to me. Further, when 'How' is removed, the sentence suddenly sounds off.

Very queer you are.


Odd that is.

I can imagine such sentences being used in, say, a poem, but it doesn't seem to me to be a grammatical construction. Or might these sentences actually be correct, and would that suggest that English can be OSV/SOV? What is the grammatical function of 'How'? Is it some sort of adverb? Or perhaps an interjection?
Is this construction acceptable with other verbs?

Him you killed!


The dancing lady from afar I had seen, then you approaching her with ill-intent I witnessed.

Are these sentences acceptable? Can 'how' be used before them too?

How him you killed!


How the dancing lady from afar I had seen, then you approaching her with ill-intent I witnessed!


@PM 2 Yes, Yoda-speak; and perfectly intelligible to English speakers, even long ago in a galaxy far, far away.

Who was the British comedian whose catch-phrase was 'Ow queer! ?

OP, you do know that 'queer' can have a special meaning?

@MichaelHarvey what do you mean? I meant it as in 'odd' or 'unusual', but I'm aware it's used to describe the LGBTQIA+ community

@Scella - in Britain, if you are under 60, the default meaning of 'queer' is likely to be 'LGBTQIA+', so much so that even older people will often avoid using it with the older 'unusual' meaning.

@MichaelHarvey that's great to know. Thank you. I did know it was on the decline but I wasn't aware it's that rare already

Who are the who migrated this from ELU?

Compare to the line from Little Red Riding Hood, “Why, Grandmother, such big ears you have.” Or to the more contemporary “What an amazing meal she served at Christmas.”
The inversion of the standard word order in such constructions is a means of placing heightened emphasis on one portion by moving it forward to the beginning of the sentence.
(And note that your sentence, How very queer you are! has no object. Its deep structure is essentially You are [how] very queer!)

In this context, how is an "intensifier", like so in You are [ever] so queer! I think AmE in particular used to use "And how!" as emphatic recognition of the scale / force / truth value of some preceding statement. Note that the "emphatic inversion" of, say, So soft your skin is isn't just facetious "Yoda speech". It's been around as a literary / poetic device for centuries.

"The dancing lady I had seen, but I hadn't noticed the man in black who was watching her in the shadows."

It's not easy to apply a "fronted intensifier" to dancing lady, but I'd say Dr John's Such a night effectively uses such for emphasis, similar to How memorable that night was! It was so confusing!

YYUR, YYUB, ICURYY 4 me.

Hmmm.  "All such constructions invert the standard word order as a means of placing heightened emphasis on one portion by moving it forward to the beginning of the sentence." <-- How about  "What a disaster awaited them when they got hoem", for example?

Yes, @Araucaria-Him, I read your example as completely analogous to my What an amazing meal she served at Christmas. Do you see it differently?

@PaulTanenbaum Yes, I think I do. Because in your case what an amazing meal is the object of the verb served and has thus been moved to initial position. However, in  my example, what a disaster has moved nowhere, because it's the subject of the matrix verb.

@FumbleFingers - I saw Doctor John live! in 1972.

@Araucaria-Nothereanymore, I see what you mean and have edited my answer to reduce the risk of that misinterpretation.
